# Java AWT: Setting background of Canvas changes the background for the whole frame

Tags: java, canvas, awt, layout-manager

Why is it that changing the background color for the [java.awt.Canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html), changes the background for the whole frame?

I set up a Frame object as follows:

```
public class Gui extends Frame {

    public Gui() {

        setSize(800, 600);
        setLocation(0, 0);

        Canvas cd=new Canvas();
        cd.setSize(500, 300);
        cd.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        add(cd);


        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
                System.exit(0);
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        paintComponents(g);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Gui g=new Gui();
        g.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

The above code sets the frame size to be 800x600, then adds a significantly smaller canvas to it - 500x300, and finally sets the background color to be `Color.BLUE`, but instead of getting a 500x300 blue rectangle inside a bigger, 800x600 window-frame (with default grey color), the result is a 800x600 frame with blue background:

[image]

The docs says:

> public void setBackground(Color c)
>
> Sets the background color of this component.
>
> The background color affects each component differently and the parts
>   of the component that are affected by the background color may differ
>   between operating systems.

Could that be the issue (I'm running this on Ubuntu)?
Or am I missing something else here?

Comment: Don't expect to get any help on depricated stuff, they don't even teach them in college anymore.

Comment: Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Comment: I use AWT because I need to use JFreeChart (http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/) which supports only AWT components, as far as I know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default layout of a `Frame` is `BorderLayout` (though a lot of the example code using the AWT based `Frame` class was written in a time when the default layout was `FlowLayout`).  Without layout constraints, a component added to a `BorderLayout` will end up in the `CENTER` constraint which stretches a component so it fits to the available height and width.

Instead we might use a `GridBagLayout`.  When we add a single component to a `GridBagLayout` without any constraint, it will be centered and the size will be respected.  E.G. (See further comments in code.)

[image: Centered Canvas in Frame]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Gui extends Frame {

    public Gui() {
        setSize(400, 200);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        Canvas cd=new Canvas();
        // TODO: Override rather than set & make it preferred rather than actual
        cd.setSize(300, 100); 
        cd.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        add(cd);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        //paintComponents(g); // wrong method!
        super.paint(g); // right method, but does nothing different to original!
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO: AWT/Swing based GUIs should be started on the EDT
        Gui g=new Gui();
        g.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "AWT/Swing based GUIs should be started on the EDT"?
Do you mean that it must run on separate thread?

Comment: See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) & particularly **[Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)** for more details.